# How to install multiple Ionic (Capacitor) apps in the same device?

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

When I install a second **Ionic Capacitor app** in the **same device**, it overwrites the previously installed one. How can I prevent this to happen and have two or more applications installed simultaneously?

I've read in other posts that one possible solution is adding`id` attribute into `config.xml` file:

```
<widget id="my.id" ... >
```

But this file is regenerated every time I build my application and the `id` is removed.

Answer (score 0):

For Capacitor projects, just modify `appId` property in `capacitor.config.ts` file:

```js
const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: 'com.mydomain.myappname',
  appName: 'CNC Service SDRP',
  ...
};
```

According [Capacitor documentation](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config), the unique identifier:

> ...must be in reverse domain name notation, generally representing a domain name that you or your company owns.

**Rebuild** your project. To be 100% sure, remove `android` folder (make backup first) and build again.

Note: it's not necessary to modify `config.xml`; that apparently works for Cordova projects.